# Angular 13, how to use an exported type to define data properly

Tags: angular, typescript

I had a guide I was going off, and hit a snag when my code threw an error and theirs didn't.

Error: Property 'currentQuiz' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

I defined a type to match the response from my API:

```
export type Quiz = {
    quiz: [{
      question: string,
      choices: [{
        text: string,
        correct: boolean
      }],
      order: number
    }],
    highScore: number
  }
```

And now I'm trying to use it in the component where I'm making the API call:

```
export class GameWindowComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private _apiService: apiService) {

  }
  // the line throwing the error:
  currentQuiz: Quiz
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this._apiService.getQuiz(window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.currentQuiz = res
    })
  } 
}
```

I'm thinking this is likely a version mismatch between my app (angular 13) and the tutorial (not sure but thought it was 13). What am I missing here?

I've seen other ways of stating Quiz (eg. Quiz[]) but it just doesn't like anything where I use a ':' to set the type of currentQuiz.

The API call is working, and the data types specified in the type Quiz align exactly with the response object.

Comment: What is the error..?

Comment: Does the error complain that there's a type mismatch? Does `this._apiService.getQuiz()` emit and the subscription's callback expect a Quiz object - the one you're assigning later on to `this.currentQuiz`? Setting the correct types might point you in the right direction.

Comment: The error is: Property 'currentQuiz' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

Comment: The reason is not that you use an exported type. It's not an Angular error also. It's Typescript error. If you just use assumption operator, it'll be fine. Just like this; currentQuiz!: Quiz;